# vue-router: browser attempts to open <router-link> as a local file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm new to Vue-router and can't figure out what's gone awry.  Clicking on a navigation link causes the desired component to be displayed for an instant, but then the browser tries to open the component as if it were a file.

For example, clicking on the "Badger!" link results in the browser attempting to open a local file named `file:///home/travis/.../prototype/dist/badger` which of course results in a file not found error.

Any insights on this?  I've tried to follow existing examples carefully.

**main.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Badger from './component/Badger.vue';
import Grid from './component/Grid.vue';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: __dirname,
  routes: [
    { path: '/badger', component: Badger },
    { path: '/grid', component: Grid },
  ]
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
});
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <router-link to="/badger">Badger!</router-link>
            </li>
            <li>
                <router-link to="/grid">Data!</router-link>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('mounted App component')
        },
        data() {
            // ...
            }
        },
    }
</script>

<style>
    // ...
</style>
```

Comment: It looks like you are running your app directly from local file system instead of http.

Comment: check the value of `__dirname` for `base: __dirname,` This might be causing it.

Comment: @bigless Yes.  Ideally the build would generate an artifact that I could open from the filesystem or from a server.

Comment: its not possible to serve your app.html on '/' with file system like nginx or others do. Simply, file system is not suitable environment for http routing. Serve your app via http and let us know if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the router is in `history` mode, the build artifacts must be delivered to the browser from an http server, as @bigless mentioned.

If your workflow requires opening the build artifact from the local filesystem, that can be done if you remove these lines from the router declaration:

```
  mode: 'history',
  base: __dirname,
```

This will put you in "hash mode" (the default state).  Your artifact can then be loaded either from an http server or from the local filesystem.

Relevant docs: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

Comment: Excellent, this is a must-do for running on a local filesystem without HTTP. Also, for Vue 3 and Vue Router 4, `history: createWebHashHistory()` is the way to go.